# edebug-trace ceased to exist

Tags: debugging, emacs

In Emacs 25.2, suddenly the variable `edebug-trace` ceased to exist. When I set it with `setq`, it has no effect (the trace buffer does not appear). What could have happened and how can I fix it?

Comment: I presume the `edebug` library is actually loaded? I can't replicate the issue in 25.2 -- that variable exists, and functions as advertised.

Comment: @phils `edebug-defun` exists. Is this a clear sign that the library is loaded?

Comment: No, because `edebug-defun` is autoloaded, so Emacs knows about it without the library being loaded. If you were to *call* that function, OTOH, the library would then be loaded. `(featurep 'edebug)` will return `t` if `edebug` has been loaded.

Comment: @phils `(featurep 'edebug)` returns `t`, but the variable does not exist... In the meanwhile, is there another way to know which function gets called when I click on an org-mode link?

Comment: So with `edebug` loaded, `C-h v edebug-trace` doesn't find anything? If you `M-x find-library RET edebug RET` and `C-s edebug-trace` there's no `defcustom edebug-trace` definition?

Comment: You could use `C-h k` to find out which command is called when you click on the link (probably `org-open-at-mouse`), and then `M-x debug-on-entry` to trigger the debugger when that function is called, and keep stepping through with `d` until you reach the function you're interested in. I suggest you `M-x load-library RET org.el RET` first to reduce the amount of byte code shown in the debugger.

Comment: @phils Yes, there is `defcustom edebug-trace`... and now I see it in `describe-variable` as well, but no trace buffer after setting it to `t` and clicking on the link...

Comment: I've never used edebug's tracing, so I'm unsure how it's supposed to work. Does it only trace instrumented functions?

Comment: @phils It creates a buffer in which there is a complete trace of what goes on. No instrumentation is needed.

Comment: So you've used this in the past, and now it's behaviour has changed compared to what you've previously observed?

Comment: @phils Exactly.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: I'm pretty sure your memory is faulty: `edebug-trace` has always relied on Edebug instrumentation to perform the tracing.  IOW it only traces those functions that you have instrumented with Edebug.

Answer (score 1):

> In the meanwhile, is there another way to know which function gets called when I click on an org-mode link

You could use `trace.el` to trace all `org` functions like so (I suggest not evaluating this until you're ready to click the link).

```el
(mapatoms
 (lambda (sym)
   (and (fboundp sym)
        (string-prefix-p "org-" (symbol-name sym))
        (trace-function-foreground sym))))
```

Afterwards, you can remove the traces with:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `untrace-all` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Edit: We could also convert that into a command ala `elp-instrument-package`:

```el
(defun my-trace-package (prefix)
  "Trace all functions which start with PREFIX.
For example, to trace all ELP functions, do the following:

\\[my-trace-package] RET elp- RET"
  (interactive ;; derived from `elp-instrument-package'.
   (list (completing-read "Prefix of package to trace: "
                          obarray 'my-traceable-p)))
  (if (zerop (length prefix))
      (error "Tracing all Emacs functions would render Emacs unusable"))
  (mapc (lambda (name)
          (trace-function-foreground (intern name)))
        (all-completions prefix obarray 'my-traceable-p))
  (message "Use %s to cease tracing."
           (substitute-command-keys "\\[untrace-all]")))

(defun my-traceable-p (fun)
  "Predicate for `my-trace-package'."
  (or (functionp fun) (macrop fun)))
```

Comment: In `my-traceable-p`, the `symbolp` test seems redundant.  OTOH the subsequent tests aren't quite precise enough.  I think testing `(or (functionp fun) (macrop fun))` would be a better option.

Comment: I'll update accordingly. I felt the same about the `symbolp` test, but that was based on the `elp-profilable-p` code (and the use of that predicate by `elp-instrument-package`), so I kept it in case there was something I wasn't seeing.